# Need mathematical help with loop invariant

Tags: algorithms

I was wondering about following. I have condition in my program that I want to prove its correctness (I won't write the whole problem, just the part I'm curious about):

- **if** $w \leq r$ **then** $r:=r-w$;

What I'm trying to do is form loop invariant and I have the following problem (might sound silly but I'm clueless as of what to write).

$r_{j+1}= r_{j} + w_j \times {condition}$

I want to find a condition that holds following stuff: if $w\leq r$ return $1$ else return $0$ so I could just put it mathematically in $r_{j+1}$ above so it holds. I have no clue which expression should I form that gives $1$ if $w \leq r$ else $0$. I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always explicitly define such a function.

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, \quad x \leq y\\
0, \quad otherwise\\\end{cases}$

And yes, this is a well defined function and such functions are very often used in mathematics, so you don't have to worry.